# I can't find the analytical expression of the sum from this probability problem

Tags: probability, summation, factorial

It originates from this problem:

- We have a box with $n$ balls that are evenly mixed, all are
  $\color{blue}{blue}$ except for one that is $\color{red}{red}$.
- If we pick blindly one ball per try and after each try we don't put
  it back in the box, what is the average number of tries it will take
  us to take get the $\color{red}{red}$ ball $?$.
- If I'm correct the probability of picking the $\color{red}{red}$ ball at the try number $x$ is: $$
  P[X=x]=\frac{(n-x)!}{n!},\quad X = \mbox{number of tries.}
  $$
- Thus the expected value of $X$ is:
  $$
   E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^{n}x\frac{(n-x)!}{n!}
  $$
  whose 'clean' analytical expression I can't find.

Could you help me advance in the problem please $?$. Unfortunately the book where I found the problem doesn't have the solution.

Comment: You are not correct.  Each position for the red ball is equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

The red ball is equally likely to come in any position.  There are $(n+1)!$ orders is which the balls may be drawn, and in $n!$ of them the red ball is in position $k$, for any $1\leq k\leq n+1$ so the probability, that the red ball is in position $k$ is $\frac1{n+1}$

Now I'm sure you'll find it easy to finish.

Comment: Note that after we pick a ball we don't put it back in the box.

Comment: @posilon I must be forgetting how to read.